# How to create a section group in gas

Tags: assembly, gcc, elf, gnu-assembler

What is the proper way to create a section group in gas? From the [section part](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Section.html#Section), it says to use:

> .section name , "flags"G, @type, GroupName[, linkage]

I tried defining something like:

```
.section one, "awG",@progbits,"MyGroup"
.string "1"
.section onetwo, "awG", @progbits, "MyGroup"
.string "2"
```

But then when looking at the elf file it doesn't seem to have any groups:

```
$ readelf file2 -g
There are no section groups in this file.
```

First, what would be the proper way to create a group; and secondly, are groups useful at all? (I don't think I've seen them in most compiler output).

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Assembling your example file and then using readelf on the resulting object file shows the existence of the `MyGroup` group. If you're trying to use readelf on a linked executatable then what I said previously about you looking in the wrong place applies here as well.

Comment: @RossRidge thanks could you show the commands you used to assemble/link?

Comment: If I you think I linked something then you've completely misunderstood what I've been saying.

Comment: @RossRidge oh, I see now. Just doing `$ readelf file2.o -a -W` on the object file -- yes this shows the groups now, that was the issue. So are groups only a 'thing' on non-executable files then?

Comment: @RossRidge are groups used at all with compilers? I can't seem to find any usages of it in playing around with some compilers and googling a bit.

Comment: The [`annobin` GCC plug-in](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/02/20/annobin-storing-information-binaries/) uses section groups, but it led to some discussions, so I suspect it was the first user in the current GNU toolchain. But due to internal GCC implementation details, it needs an `.attach_to_group` pseudo-opcode in GAS.